# HTTPS/SSL for react application

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I configure HTPS/SSL for a react app? I have the package.json file and openssl selfsigned certificates. The NPM start command starts react application in http only.

It's a web apllication.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you added usesClearTextTraffic in your android manifest :

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Hope it helps you. feel free for doubts